# How to write Mongo Geospatial query in PHP?

Tags: mongodb, php-mongodb

I have a geospatial query Like Follwing Query.. This Query return 4 Records.. I want to Frame Following Query in PHP

```
db.master.find({ location:
   { $geoWithin:
      { $centerSphere: [ [ 94.60867254, 27.54018825 ], 10 / 6378.1 ] } } })
```

How to Frame above query in php? and get result?

Answer (score 0):

You should check the Mongo documentation for PHP [here](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-php-library) and [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/php-library/master/)

Comment: `$query = array('location' =>
    array("\$geoWithin"=>
      array("\$centerSphere"=>array($long, $lat), 5/6378.1)
    )
);` This is Correct one ? @Eric

Comment: But i have Doubt, Why we use '\'(slash) before Every operator like `\$geoWithin` ?@ Eric